# How to rearrange Grid items without using Media Queries

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to know, if it's possible to rearrange items in CSS Grid without using Media Queries.

I need rearrange some items in my Modal Window component and therefore I can't use Media Queries.

On the picture below, I've got graphical scenario of my desired result. The numbers are for example some checkbox items.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: When is the transition supposed to occur?

Answer (score 0):

If you set in `grid-template-columns` just to one column, i think it will give your desired output

```
.grid-container{
  ...
  grid-template-columns: auto; // this means 1 column
  grid-template-columns: auto auto // this means 2 column so on an so forth
}
```